# How can I play an XBox 360 game if the disk is unreadable?

Tags: xbox-360

I recently bought FIFA 14 and somehow I managed to knock my Xbox over and create a massive burn ring on the disk. The game reads and works right up to the title screen, then it says 'Disk Is Unreadable' like any other scratched or burnt disk.

Now I know of all the DIY tricks to try and fix this, but obviously finding someone with the game, installing the game, and then using my disk as a 'key' is less risky and should still work, right? Only problem is I don't know anybody with FIFA 14 on Xbox 360, and in South Africa you can't rent Xbox games because DVD rental places don't really exist anymore.

Since I bought the game, 100% original and all, is there a way to download a FIFA 14 image and install it onto my Xbox, the same way you would with a friends disk or doesn't it work like that? Is there another way that I don't know about?

Comment: Just buy the game again?

Comment: If the disk is unreadable, what makes you think installing it and using it as a key would work?

Comment: If you bought it legit then then EA should be able to supply you with a replacement if you send them the scratched one.

Comment: @Adsy Assuming the user does have a legally purchased copy already, they also already have a license. Buying the game yet again would, then, be rather ridiculous.

Comment: @FEichinger doesn't seem like he has much of a choice in this situation

Comment: @Adsy Contacting whoever handed out the license (EA, I believe) to get a replacement medium would be a perfectly valid option. They might charge a fee (shipping, etc.), but that's about it.

Comment: @FEichinger good luck with that from EA

Comment: @Adsy Whether or not they're *willing* to do that is completely independent from whether or not it's an option. For all we know, they might add a unicorn that barfs honey to the package.

Comment: A search would seem to indicate that if you registered it on Origin then you can download it from there and not have to use the disc at all. Don't know how true that is.

Comment: @AlanB That's for PC, not Xbox 360.

Comment: @FEichinger If it's EA, you'd have to buy the honey through separate micro-transactions.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not a legitimate way to download the FIFA 14 install image from the internet to load it onto your Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

Once the "*Donut Ring*" scratch has been burnt into the disc, it can very frustrating to attempt to get the game working as you every time you attempt to, it gets further and further into the game before rejecting the disc and saying "*Disc Unreadable*", however it is a very low possibility you can recover disc data from that disc.

**Is there a way? - Of course!**

Attempting DIY is an option and worth trying because at the end of the day, the disc is not going to work by itself, but in your circumstances I can see the problem. My suggested options, although they may not apply in your location:

In my local area with GAME, if you purchase a game you have up to 14 days to return it as long as the product is in the same quality and standard as when you purchased it. Therefore I have done this in the past and although it is frowned upon, has no real harm. Purchase a pre-owned FIFA 14 from a store and download it, after the download is done try your FIFA 14 and if it works Hoorah! Just return it with the excuse that your console can't read the disc.

If that isn't an option for you my only other suggestion in your case is to buy the game again, annoying but we have all had to deal with it. Personally I have had to experience this around 14 times, every single time the same reason; I charge my controller using a play and charge kit, wire wraps around my foot and as I stand up my Xbox console launches off the desk. However reality is reality and we all have to face it, some of us are more lucky than others. **However, if you don't feel like buying another FIFA 14 due to price, purchase another game for a lower price to keep you entertained until the price has dropped.**

*Really hope this rambling has helped, just a few suggestions for you. Really hope it all works out for you!*

Answer (score -2):

You actually can repair your disk using something called a "Disk Doctor" or a "Skip Doctor."

A disk doctor is a combination of a special resurfacing spray and a buffer (can be motorized, or just a brush that you rub the CD with)

The idea is that the actual data on the CD is burnt in very deep, but scratches and other stuff tends to only be on the surface. You can therefore "buffer away" the surface scratches, returning your disk to as good as new.

I've tried such technology before and I can say that, at least in certain situations, it absolutely works.

Here is one I've found that is affordable. I make no warranties as to it working:

[http://www.amazon.com/SkipDr-Manual-Disc-Repair-System/dp/B0015ACUKC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0015ACUKC)

Comment: those devices only really work for minor scratches and marks. not giant burn rings as asked. Also they tend to do more damage to the disk than it originally had.

Comment: @JLaBella Sounds good, do you have any evidence that back that up?

Comment: How about 15 years in the industry.  Those products are good for minor scratches they can't fix a disk that's burnt

Comment: I just suggested this to a mate last week and he informed me that Xbox360 disks are not like the older type disks that have multiple layers. Basically,(I'll look it up, but I'll get this in before you do that.) you have a good chance of completly wrecking the game as my friend found out with nothing to lose. It could work, I'm stubborn and am going to try it on one of my games to be sure.(Stupid, yes. For the cause, no.) The disk doctor is awesome as it is a buffer, although some video stores have a buffer that will remove layers off the disk, they'll charge about $2. Don't do it, till I do.

Answer (score -2):

Rent a game from an internet site like lovefilm, that way they post it to you and then you return it in a certain amount of days. Either that, or find a disk image somewhere (obviously you cant get a legit one) and burn it to a dvd (Tesco ones are best)

Hope this helps!